# Meteor 'forgets' the logged in user

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm facing a problem with Meteor at the moment. I recently developed my first full Meteor Website, and am also using Facebook login for the first time. The problem is that the sign in process is a multi-level setup which works fine when running it locally on my computer, but doesn't work the moment I put it on my host. When logging in on the host, I can retrieve the user ID through the console, but after a second or 2 the value becomes null.

Here's what I've got -

Sign-in.js:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook(
    {
     requestPermissions: ["manage_pages","publish_stream"],
     requestOfflineToken: true
    },
    function(err){
     if(err)
     {
       notify.error( err );
       return;
     }

     Meteor.call("initFacebook",{},function(){
       Meteor.call("authorizeUser",{},function(err,res){
          Router.go("/admin");
       });
     });

 });
```

AuthorizeUser.js (Server)

```
Meteor.methods({
   'authorizeUser': function(){
     if(authorizedUser() && !Meteor.user().authorized)
     {
       Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.user()._id}, {"authorized": "true"});
       console.log("Authorized");
     }
     else
       console.log("Not authorized");
   }
});
```

Looking at the server-side log, the update completes successfully and console.log("Authorized") is triggered. I presume the issue lies with updating the user whilst he's logged in, but I can't figure out why, and what I should be doing instead. Regardless, it looks like the user ID is forgotten the moment that authorizeUser returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with a solution for the problem through looking at the way some others approached the same problem that I was trying to solve - e.g. adding data to a user profile after or during their log-in.

When Meteor creates a new user it calls the server-side method Accounts.onCreateUser( [func] ), which is intended for this particular purpose - extending your accounts with extra information fetched from anywhere. As my original suspicion was with the update method in the AuthorizeUser method, this seemed like a sensible way to get around it.

After removing the Meteor.methods method for "authorizeUser", and modifying Meteor.loginWithFacebook to the following:

```
 Meteor.loginWithFacebook(
    {
     requestPermissions: ["manage_pages","publish_stream"],
     requestOfflineToken: true
    },
    function(err){
     if(err)
     {
       notify.error( err );
       return;
     } 
     Router.go('/admin');
 });
```

As well as adding a server-side method for Accounts.onCreateUser:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){

  user.authorized = authorizedUser();

  return user;
});
```

Meteor successfully logged me in on the host, and retained the user data correctly, both during the session and in the database. Thanks everyone for your time, and I hope that this solution may help someone facing the same type of problem in the future.